# Julia: Extract Zip files within a Zip file

Tags: julia, zip

I'm using Julia's ZipFile package to extract and process csv files.  No problem, but when I encounter a zip file within the zip file, I'd like to process that as well, but am encountering an error.

Julia ZipFile docs are here: https://zipfilejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Here's the code:

```
using ZipFile
using DataFrames
function process_zip(zip::ZipFile.ReadableFile)

    if split(zip.name,".")[end] == "zip"

        r = ZipFile.Reader(zip) #error: MethodError: no method matching seekend(::ZipFile.ReadableFile)

        for f in r.files
            process_zip(f) 
        end
    end

    if split(zip.name,".")[end] == "csv"
         df = readtable(zip) #for now just read it into a dataframe
    end

end

r = ZipFile.Reader("yourzipfilepathhere");

for f in r.files
    process_zip(f)
end
close(r)
```

The call to ZipFile.Reader gives the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching seekend(::ZipFile.ReadableFile)
Closest candidates are:
  seekend(::Base.Filesystem.File) at filesystem.jl:191
  seekend(::IOStream) at iostream.jl:57
  seekend(::Base.AbstractIOBuffer) at iobuffer.jl:178
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] _find_enddiroffset(::ZipFile.ReadableFile) at /home/chuck/.julia/v0.6/ZipFile/src/ZipFile.jl:259
 [2] ZipFile.Reader(::ZipFile.ReadableFile, ::Bool) at /home/chuck/.julia/v0.6/ZipFile/src/ZipFile.jl:104
 [3] process_zip(::ZipFile.ReadableFile) at ./In[27]:7
 [4] macro expansion at ./In[27]:18 [inlined]
 [5] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

So it seems ZipFile package cannot process a zip file from a zip file as it cannot do a seekend on it.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I think you will probably have to first unzip the zip files and then recurse on them after they are extracted.

Comment: Should I unzip to a diskfile, or can I unzip to a memory file?  I'm new to Julia and I don't know how to create a memory file.

Comment: It seems like it works only on files, but you might try to get around that by wrapping your memory zip object into a file-like class implementing the required methods for ZipFile to manipulate the zip object. But let's see if someone with more experience with Julia can provide you with a more elegant solution.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I'm not interested in keeping the extracted zip file on disk, I'm only interested in processing the contents.  I guess I'll have to figure out how to read the zip into a file like memory object compatable with ReadableFile

Comment: Thanks, lets wait and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to read the zip file into an IOBuffer.  ZipFile.Reader is able to process the IOBuffer.  Here is the working code:

```
using ZipFile
using DataFrames
function process_zip(zip::ZipFile.ReadableFile)

    if split(zip.name,".")[end] == "zip"

        iobuffer = IOBuffer(readstring(zip))
        r = ZipFile.Reader(iobuffer)

        for f in r.files
            process_zip(f) 
        end
    end

    if split(zip.name,".")[end] == "csv"
         df = readtable(zip) #for now just read it into a dataframe
    end

end

r = ZipFile.Reader("yourzipfilepathhere");

for f in r.files
    process_zip(f)
end
close(r)
```